# How can I programatically remove missing references?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some Spreadsheets created in Excel 2010 and we are slowly implementing Windows 10 (and Office 365). So once some of my files are opened by someone using Excel 2016 and saved, when someone who is still on Excel 2010 tries to open the file, they get an error linked to Missing References.

I know how to manually fix it, but unfortunately not everyone does. So I've been looking for a way to do it automatically.

I found the following code, but for some reason, when I apply it, it just freezes Excel and crashes.

Anyone know why it doesn't work?

*** In a Standard Module ***

```
Sub References_RemoveMissing() 
     'Macro purpose:  To remove missing references from the VBE

    Dim theRef As Variant, i As Long 

    On Error Resume Next 

    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1 
        Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i) 
        If theRef.isbroken = True Then 
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef 
        End If 
    Next i 

    If Err <> 0 Then 
        MsgBox "A missing reference has been encountered!" _ 
        & "You will need to remove the reference manually.", _ 
        vbCritical, "Unable To Remove Missing Reference" 
    End If 

    On Error GoTo 0 
End Sub
```

*** In the ThisWorkbook Module ***

```
    Call References_RemoveMissing 
End Sub
```

Comment: Removing the missing references will NOT allow the code to run (unless you're using only late-bound objects). They'll still need to add the appropriate, version-specific references. So perhaps it is better to let the user identify the broken ones via the UI, and replace them with the appropriate references manually. Rather than deleting them programmatically and letting the user fend for herself.

Comment: Your `If Err <> 0 Then ` block should probably belong within the `For i ...` block.

Comment: Probably not the response you wanted, but I'd just have a XL2010 version and an XL2016 version separate. Trying to fix a compile error at run-time is never going to work...

Comment: the issue is that while going from Win 7 to Win 10, we are automatically getting office 360. So using both is not an option... @Sam

Comment: That would be so easy if I could give them that answer, unfortunately, that's not an option.
We have to have people moving from Win 7 to Win 10 and they refuse to do so because of these issues. They won't accept having to add these extra steps to their workflow, which is why i need a solution @DavidZemens

Comment: Refactor the code to use only late binding.